# Python print array in one print function

Tags: python, arrays, printing

For example I have an array of two elements array = ['abc', 'def'].
 How do I print the whole array with just one function. like this: `print "%s and %s" % array`
Is it possible? I have predefined number of elemnts, so i know how many elements would be there.

EDIT:

I am making an sql insert statement so there would be a number of credentials, let's say 7, and in my example it would look like this:

```
("insert into users values(%s, \'%s\', ...);" % array)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can also do

```
print '{0} and {1}'.format(arr[0],arr[1])
```

or in your case

```
print "insert into users values({0}, {1}, {2}, ...);".format(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2]...)
```

or

```
print "insert into users values({0}, {1}, {2}, ...);".format(*arr)
```

happy? 
make sure length of array matches the index..

Comment: This is something more likely what I'm looking for, but if it's possible to just put an array at the end

Comment: Yes this what i was looking for!

Answer (score 11):

Would

```
print ' and '.join(array)
```

satisfy you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> array = ['abc', 'def']
>>> print " and ".join(array)
abc and def
>>> array = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> print " and ".join(array)
abc and def and ghi
>>>
```

---

**Edit:**

My above post is for your original question.  Below is for your edited one:

```
print "insert into users values({}, {}, {}, ...);".format(*array)
```

Note that the number of `{}`'s must match the number of items in `array`.

Answer (score 1):

If the input array is **Integer type** then you have to first convert into **string type** array and then use `join` method for joining by `,` or space whatever you want. e.g:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 4, 3]
>>> print(", " . join(arr))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
>>> sarr = [str(a) for a in arr]
>>> print(", " . join(sarr))
1, 2, 4, 3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is:

```
print(" %s %s bla bla %s ..." % (tuple(array)))
```

where you need as many `%s` format specifiers as there are in the array.  The print function requires a tuple after the `%` so you have to use `tuple()` to turn the array into a tuple.