# How to print an initialized 2D array?

Tags: python

I want to print an initialized 2D array.
I have tried this, but it is wrong

```
>>>a=[[1,43,2], [12,3,42]]
>>>Print a
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129415/python-print-array-in-one-print-function

Answer (score 0):

Your array is fine. However, the print statement is not. In python, you should do this:

```
print(a)
```

Or

```
print a
```

for older versions of python.

Comment: This is the same exact answer as mine

Comment: Yeaah,but the printed array is continued in the same line with square brackets.

Comment: @NitinDhoundiyal what do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

This is correct: `a=[[1,43,2], [12,3,42]]`
Your print statement isn't. For Python 2.x it should be `print a` for Python 3.x it should be `print(a)`.

Comment: Still dont get why this was downvoted. Better answer than the random person who deleted their account...